# How to start with NOSQL using .net programming languages?

Tags: .net, nosql

just was reading this article http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/3/23/digg-4000-performance-increase-by-sorting-in-php-rather-than.html
And found this nice article http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel
I just want to know as a .net developer how to deal with NOSQL, and somethings like cassandra.

I found that cassandra is apache product, is there something like this in microsoft world? or articles to know how to deal with cassandra using .net?

another link may be useful: http://www.slideshare.net/jhammerb/data-presentations-cassandra-sigmod

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [LINQ Provider](http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp/tree/master/MongoDB.Linq/) for [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) (another NoSQL DB) - haven't had any experience with it yet. The Provider is just a part of a complete .NET library for accessing MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

See the answers to this Question for a good list of NoSQL solutions in .NET:

[What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net)